# SP 2013 - Document Library - Create Empty Item Placeholder

Tags: 2013, document-library

We have a set deliverable documents for a project, in one location we need to list all of them whether or not there is a file associated with the item.

[image]

Comment: Can you please elaborate your question. I am not able to understand the problem?

Comment: We are at a loss as to how to achieve creating a new item in the document library that does not contain a file until a later date. The item without the file serves as a placeholder.

Comment: Can you then replace this placeholder when document is ready and keep the related meradata and historie

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of ways you can work around this. The simplest involves creating a placeholder or dummy document, and having a status column to indicate this. It's not a great option but its workable.

You can start improving the solution by allowing other content types to be added. A common addition I use is a link to a document. Frequently you need external references to things such as legislation or regulations or standards, or documents in other libraries, and the link type helps solve this.

(The hyperlink validation SharePoint performs on URL can get in the way a bit. It's common when you reference a document in another EDRM or site that you get a query to its location with parameters delimited by '?', and SharePoint won't allow such characters.)

The other extension you can make is to create a custom content type with the minimum column/metadata you need filled out, inheriting from something like Item, and add this as a valid content type on the library. Or (which sometimes makes it easier), inherit from Document and add a template for the content type with a blank document or text saying something like "Placeholder to be updated later'.

If you need pointers:

- Library Settings -> Advanced Settings gives you the option of allowing management of content types
- Once enabled the Library settings page shows valid Content Types, and allows you to add additional site content types
- Each content type will get an additional item on the New menu. If you call your Content Type 'Placeholder', this is what people will see on the New menu
- To add a new site Content Type, Site Settings -> Site Content Types (under Web Designer Galleries)

Answer (score 0):

This is not complicated at all.  Regular Sharepoint lists should work for what you are trying to accomplish.  Create a new list with the detail on the items that you need.

Go into the list and click on the gear icon in the top right corner and select list settings.

At the bottom, click "Create View"
Click Standard View
Add "Attachments" to your view.  You will then be able to add the file as an attachment.

You can then create details and add a file later.